# Missing Property and Cash

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought one of the cash cards from the xbox store which gave me about $1.25m in-game cash for roughly £13.50 directly from my linked bank account card. Then I went and purchased the most expensive property in the game, which was $400k from the money I just bought from the store. I used the property whilst I played for a couple of hours before saving the game twice (just to make sure it did) leaving the game and switching off my xbox. A few hours afterwards, I went back online to find that the property was gone and appearing as if it was never purchased, but the $400k wasn't there either! So basically, money from my bank has gone towards downloading some in-game cash that has partially disappeared. I've sent rockstar a message but there isn't any sign of a reply. I feel like I've been robbed - it's frustrating. Any form (info/advice/updates/etc) of help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've experienced similar losses.  Thankfully, only with in game earned cash.  I'm hoping that the various servers are just slow to sync up right not and I'll log on in a few days and all the cash will be restored.  I've submitted an issue to Rockstar about it.  Still waiting to hear back.

Answer (score 1):

Online is pretty buggy right now, it's entirely possible that what you experienced is one of these bugs.
http://www.computerandvideogames.com/431870/rockstar-working-around-the-clock-to-resolve-gta-v-online-problems-errors-and-bugs/

Comment: Same thing happened to me but instead i lost all 1.25 million from my bank. support staff at rockstar only replied once for me but we will probably get our in game cash back once the server issues are resolved i hope.

Comment: I also lost the 400k property. I purchased it from the in game website. It was available, but upon joining my friend's session it was no longer in my possession. It shows on my stat sheet that I spent 400k on properties, so there is an electronic record of it in the system. I imagine Rockstar will rectify these issues, I hope.