# How do I find missions in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have been playing GTA Online for a little bit, and no mission markers are showing up. What is going on? I have done the tutorials and so forth, but there doesn't seem to be any missions in online games.

Are there any missions for GTA Online? Or is there only open world gameplay?

Comment: So, if  I am understanding you correctly, you want to know if there are any missions for GTA Online, cooperative or otherwise, aside from the open world gameplay. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, i get past the tutorial and then all there seems to be is open world play, deathmatchs and robbing stores so forth. Waiting for Lamar to call for a "job" that i'm hoping can be done with friends.

Comment: I believe there should be mission markers.  Your problem is probably one of the many, many bugs in GTA Online.  Until Rockstar say it's working, don't expect anything to work at all and be thankful when anything does.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the early game missions are triggered by phone calls from Simeon, Lamar, and one of Lamar's friends.  These should start up at about level 4.  As you level more options in free mode will appear.

I personally had problems with these events triggering automatically on day 1.  Day 2 seemed to be better in that regard.  [Though be weary, there still seems to be issues with the servers not remembering everything you've accomplished.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/133050/21097)

Comment: The missions start to appear at a certain level for each mission, I think caulynDarr is right with his lvl 4 here. Just do a couple of races and the missiosn will start showing up.

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way to do "co-op" missions is through the texts on your phone or calling a contact who will send you a text.  The abilty to request a mission from a contact opens up at different levels depending on the contact.  All the missions on the map are competition type missions, races, deathmatch etc.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your phone for contracts and current available jobs.

Answer (score 0):

All of the blue icons on the world map those are all called "**Jobs**".  Types of jobs include races, "missions", and deathmatches.  Mission jobs can be anything that's not a race or deathmatch.  Many of them, however, are "Last Team Standing" jobs which might as well be classified as deathmatch.

**If you want a "mission" type job similar to the GTA single player missions, your best bet is to call Gerald.**

Find Gerald in your contacts list and request a job.  He will text you back with a job (this can take some time).  Most of his jobs entail going somewhere, killing a bunch of people, stealing something, then delivering said something to him.  That's as close to offline GTA as I've seen.

Answer (score -2):

Call Simeon and he should answer, then it'll ask you what you want to do. Gerald really won't answer, but when you go around beating the races they won't show again because you beat them, but if you keep doing the races, etc., you will build your rp and cash. Even if you don't beat the races, etc., you'll still get that money and rp.